# Poner una imagen como botón submit en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Quiero crear un botón para eliminar un registro de una tabla, pero en lugar del típico botón, quiero usar una imagen creada.

Estoy intentando el siguiente código pero no funciona:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    {{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['ejercicios.destroy', $e->id]]) }}
    {{ Form::input('image',['class' => 'btn','src'=>'images\btns\no2.png','style'=>'margin-right: 80px;width:60px;height:60px;']) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
 </div>
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta hacerlo usando [`Form::image`](https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/master/FormBuilder.php#L696), así:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['ejercicios.destroy', $e->id]]) }}
{{ Form::image('images\btns\no2.png', 'name', ['class' => 'btn', 'style' => 'margin-right: 80px;width:60px;height:60px;']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

[Mas ejemplos aqui](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/170/creating-an-image-input-element)

Comment: Muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente los formularios de LaravelCollective deben utilizar la sintaxis de "No escape" de Blade, también es importante agregar el nombre del campo:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['ejercicios.destroy', $e->id]]) !!}
{!! Form::input('image', 'delete-btn', null, ['class' => 'btn','src'=>'images\btns\no2.png','style'=>'margin-right: 80px;width:60px;height:60px;']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada.